# Calculate Danny allowances in 2010.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In 2011, Danny received an allowance of $ 260. This amount is seeing an increase of 30% compared with the previous year. Calculate Danny allowances in 2010.

Calculation:

= 30/100 x 260

= 7800/100
= 78

= 260-78

answer = 183

**=> Refer to my exercise book, the answer is 200. Are my calculations wrong?**

Comment: Your method is not correct. Hint: Let $x$ be the allowance in $2010$. Then $x$ plus $30\%$ of $x$ is $260$. Thus $x(1.3)=260$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ be the allowance from $2010$.

Then in 2011, we have a 30% increase in allowance $x$, which we express as $0.3x$, plus (added to) the original allowance $x$, to give $0.3\cdot x + x = 260$ allowance in 2011.

We want to solve for $x$ to determine exactly what the allowance in 2010: 
$$0.3 x + x = 1.3x = 260$$

$$1.3 x = 260 \iff x = \dfrac {260}{1.3} = 200$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help ;-)

Comment: $+!{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

If $\$260$ is a 30% increase from the previous year, then, calling the previous year's value $x$, $x + .30x = \$260$, or $1.3x = \$260$. Now, dividing through by $1.3$ gives that $x = \$200$.

Basically, you read the problem as saying that the allowance in 2010 was 30% less than in 2011, which is not the same thing as that the allowance in 2011 was 30% more than in 2010.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.